# Wikidata Query Service: how do I search by freebase

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am using the Wikidata Query Service (https://query.wikidata.org) to get details about freebase ids.

I now have a list of freebase ids

`/m/0gqpg /m/0h0vk /m/0h3vhfb /m/0h4xw_ /m/0h52w /m/0hfp /m/0hhbr`

How should I modify the following code to achieve a bulk query?

```
\`SELECT  ?s ?sLabel ?p  ?o ?oLabel WHERE {
?s wdt:P646 "/m/0181lj"

SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
}
```

I would like to get the label corresponding to the freebase id

Comment: use SPARQL `VALUES` clause for inline data: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options (`FILTER` with [`IN`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in); `FILTER` with [`||`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-logical-or); [`UNION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives)), but usually the best is [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

```
SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?freebaseID
WHERE {
  
  VALUES ?freebaseID { 
    "/m/0181lj" 
    "/m/0gqpg" 
    "/m/0h0vk" 
    "/m/0h3vhfb" 
    "/m/0h4xw_" 
    "/m/0h52w" 
    "/m/0hfp" 
    "/m/0hhbr" 
  }
  
  ?s wdt:P646 ?freebaseID .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
  
}
```